# i used the image tag in html and inserted the image path when i deleted the images from my computer i cannot see the images why?

Tags: html

```
<img src="my.jpg" alt="image not found">
```

I want to insert an image into my website, the image is saved with the name 'my' in jpg format. So I mentioned "my.jpg" in the image tag to insert that particular image. Now after completing, I checked the website and it displayed the mentioned image. So when I delete the 'my.jpg' from my computer and check the website it is displaying "image not found".

Now my question is, to display or view an image on the website I created by me or others should I have it saved on my computer? or is there any other alternative or is it fixed that I must have the inserted image saved forever in my computer until I delete the website?

Also when I shared my created website they couldn't see the images I inserted. It displayed "image not found"

Comment: Did you expect the image to stay there after you deleted the image?

Comment: Your directory now acts like a web server, so you need to have every file needed for your website on your computer. When you have hosted web server then you upload there everything and it runs from that server.

Comment: i get it now thank you

Comment: @martin when i shared it they couldn't see the image so i need a web server for that too?

Comment: @Spectric yes.....

Comment: @tiny if you want your website to be available on the internet, you need to have hosted web server. Now you don't have hosted, you have `local` server.